# IronPython compiler version at runtime

Tags: ironpython

How to get IronPython compiler version at runtime (interactive session)?

Answer (score 7):

You can find out the current version via the [sys](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) module:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.4.0 (IronPython 1.1.2 (1.1.2) on .NET 2.0.50727.3603)'
```