# Running Python Script from C# with IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

While I am trying to run python code from C# with Iron Python I get some exceptions tried writing code inside C# but it didn't change anything. Is there any other option to run python code inside C#? or Am I doing something wrong with my code? In python everything works great Until I run it from C#

```
private static string GetBitcoinPrivateKeyFromMnemonic(string mnemonic)
{
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
var dir1 = @"/home/hackslash/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages";
var dir2 = @"/usr/lib/python3.7";
paths.Add(dir1);
paths.Add(dir2);
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(@"/home/hackslash/Magnify/MagnifyDevelopment/Python/bitcoin.py");
dynamic bitcoin = py.Bitcoin();
var bitcoinPrivateWIF = bitcoin.generate_bitcoin_private_wif(mnemonic);
return bitcoinPrivateWIF;
}
```

and I have this file in Python

```
from btctools import *
import hashlib


class Bitcoin:

@classmethod
def generate_bitcoin_address_from_wif(cls, private_key_wif):
    private_key = PrivateKey.from_wif(private_key_wif)
    public_key = private_key.to_public()
    public_address = public_key.to_address('P2PKH', compressed=False)

    return public_address

@classmethod
def generate_bitcoin_private_wif(cls, mnemonic):
    hashed_words = hashlib.sha256(mnemonic.encode()).hexdigest()

    private_key = PrivateKey.from_hex(hashed_words)
    private_wif = private_key.wif(compressed=False)

    return private_wif
```

I get this Exception:
`Unhandled Exception:
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: invalid syntax
  at IronPython.Runtime.ThrowingErrorSink.Add (Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceUnit, System.String message, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceSpan span, System.Int32 errorCode, Microsoft.Scripting.Severity severity) [0x0001a] in <0569a20e5dd94f74a766cc11c6214b7c>:0 
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError (System.Int32 start, System.Int32 end, System.String message, System.Int32 errorCode) [0x0003a] in <0569a20e5dd94f74a766cc11c6214b7c>:0 
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError (System.Int32 start, System.Int32 end, System.String message) [0x00000] in <0569a20e5dd94f74a766cc11c6214b7c>:0 
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError (System.String message) [0x00027] in <0569a20e5dd94f74a766cc11c6214b7c>:0 
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.AddTrailers (IronPython.Compiler.Ast.Expression ret, System.Boolean allowGeneratorExpression) [0x00103] in <0569a20e5dd94f74a766cc11c6214b7c>:0`

Comment: The indentation of the Python code shown here is wrong. Is it really indented this way?

Comment: Yeah Stack did that thing to my code python code work fine with pycharm

Comment: If there is no way to get a better error description (I'm not used to IronPython) first try to execute a very simple script (e.g. one only containing a single digit like `1`). If this works try a reduced version of the actual script. My guess is that `from btctools import *` imports something with a bad syntax. Maybe the IronPython version doesn't support a used feature of Python 3.7.

Comment: You mean to import all needed file manually without `*` this?

Comment: No this won't help here. The actual importing (and parsing of the code) happens nevertheless. Just try first the `1` file and then a file only containing `from btctools import *`.

Comment: Just tried that it didnt change anything and on thing about the exception it is too big to post it here Stack doesn't allow me to post it here

Comment: Did you also try a file consisting of `1` only? Did this work? Do you know which Python version is supported by your IronPython (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643974/ironpython-compiler-version-at-runtime) how to find out)?

Comment: 2.7.9 (IronPython 2.7.9 (2.7.9.0) on Mono 4.0.30319.42000 (64-bit)) this is my version

Comment: Setting search paths for modules to those of Python 3.7 isn't a good idea then. It seems that `btctools` works for Python 2.7 but you should maybe install a CPython 2.7, test the code with this and if it works, point to the modules provided there (although I'm not sure that this will work).

Comment: Yeah I will try that thank you let you know if it works